# What are the steps to simulate data showing bias when missing data are MAR

Tags: r, simulation, missing-data

I have been trying to simulate data that shows bias in the estimated regression coefficients when there is data Missing At Random. In this case I am not interested in the estimated coefficients themselves, but on the predictions that the model makes.

To do this I have followed these steps:

1. Generate two uncorrelated explanatory variables. In my current iteration, my x1 is distributed as beta(0.5, 0,5) and x2 is uniform.
2. Generate an outcome according to some linear model, plus random error. Currently I have a quadratic term for x1 (plus the linear term) and linear in x2.
3. Split the data into two sets (training and testing)
4. Fit the corresponding model that was used to generate the data on the training data, and use this model to make predictions on the test data, and compute some measure of accuracy (I have been using root mean squared error)
5. Create missingness in one explanatory variable in the training set such that the probability of being missing is proportional to the the value of the other variable.
6. Fit a model to this dataset, use it to make predictions on the test set, and compute the RMSE

So far I have been unable to show any bias based on RMSE. I would be happy to share my code, but I don't want the question to be closed due to it being a programming question. I would like to know if my approach is reasonable. If anyone can point to some examples of this being done, I would be grateful.

Comment: Some questions : how is it supposed to be MAR if "probability of being missing is proportional to the the value of the other variable"? What are the sample size of sets and how much missing data is there?

Comment: @POC - that's the definition of MAR missingness that I was taught. I've been looking at sample sizes between 50 and 500 and simulating between 30 and 60% missingness.